# How can I tell a class that it will be the parent class of another type and that it has access to certain data member from its subclass?

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to define a set of template functions that I can later add to another class in order to provide a subset of functions that can act on a certain type.

For example, this is a generic functor that calls `size()`:

```
// provides the `size()` operation
template<class T>
struct size_op_t
{
    auto size() const noexcept
    {
        // we know that some class is inheriting from us here and that it will have
        // a data member called "value_"
        return value_.size(); // ERROR: there is no "value_" in size_op_t
    }
};
```

The issue is that there is no `value_` data member in `size_op_t`. Therefore, compilation fails. However, I know that `size_op_t` will be inherited from by a class that will in fact contain a `value_` data member.

Here's what it would look like:

```
template<class T, template<class...> class... Ops> // functions compatible with T
struct viewer : public Ops<viewer<T>>... // available functions are inherited
{
    viewer(T const& value) noexcept : value_{ value } {}

    T const& value_;
};
```

It could then be used like this:

```
std::string str{ "abc" };
viewer<std::string, size_op_t/*other operations like begin_op_t, etc.*/> view{ str };
std::cout << view.size() << '\n'; // only provides the `size()` operation
```

I'm trying to avoid having to store a reference in every `xyz_op_t` while having the ability to easily create custom viewer-like types from generic functors like `size_op_t` that I can mix and match depending on what operations I want available.